# After starting my LXC Containers, My command lxc-checkconfig, gives me output as "Unable to retrieve kernel configuration"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos7, lxc, rhel7

Am a new user to Linux hence my question may sound very amateur. Please pardon me.

What might be the issue?

Below is my output.

> [root@install-kl-xxx-vm01 /]# lxc-checkconfig Kernel configuration not
>   found at /proc/config.gz; searching... lxc-checkconfig: unable to
>   retrieve kernel configuration
>
> Try recompiling with IKCONFIG_PROC, installing the kernel headers, or
>   specifying the kernel configuration path with:   CONFIG=
>   lxc-checkconfig

Comment: You should export kernel config to proc, i.e. rebuild your kernel with specified option CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC=y